# Does "shutdown /s" really not send the "close" signal to running applications? If so, why? And how to make it do so?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

Please read these:

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99273/why-has-bitcoin-core-stopped-shutting-down-when-windows-cleanly-shuts-down

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20052

I asked the first and the Github issue was created by somebody else, quoting my SE question.

They claim that Windows 10 is broken and that `shutdown /s` doesn't send the "close" signal to running programs. But can this really be true? It seems too stupid to be real. And it must have changed recently in Windows 10 if so?

Naturally, since I don't use the `/f` flag to force immediate shutdown, I want the command to do exactly what the start menu does when the user shuts down the machine that way. But this shutdown command seems to just visually notify the user (which is useless), but not send any signal to the running programs, and just immediately shut down when its internal timeout (one minute?) is up.

Is this a bug in Windows 10 or Bitcoin Core? The Bitcoin Core developers seem convinced that it's Windows' fault, but that's always FOSS developers' stance, and it seems like something very strange for MS to randomly break in a minor update?

Comment: You can use "shutdown /s /f /t x", where x =  an integer, to force a timeout in x seconds instead of the default 60s. Additionally, any number above 0 will imply "/f", so your command for a quick cmd shutdown can be "shutdown /s /t 1". The "Windows will shut down in less than a minute" banner will show for ~ 1 second, then shut down.

Answer (score 9):

`shutdown /s` does not send the close message to applications because it is not its job to do so. The command simply initiates the normal Windows shutdown procedure which does whatever is necessary.

Sending a close message wouldn't be very effective anyway. This is the same message that an application would receive when you click the close button on the applications window. It can handle this in any way it wishes.

It could shut down the application. This is the default action if no specific action is taken. But applications often intercept this message. It could prompt the user to save any open files or do this itself. It could minimize the application to the notification area. It could ask the user to confirm the shutdown. Or it could do nothing at all.

What Windows does do is send all applications a message that Windows is about to shut down and they should do whatever is necessary. Typically the application would do whatever clean-up action is necessary and then close. If the application ignores this message, or does not reply in a timely manner, the session will end. At this point there is no way for an application to stop the process.

From the information provided there is no reason to suspect a Windows problem. Not sending this message would have major consequences and would have been caught early in testing. I strongly suspect this is an application problem. Applications do not get nearly the same level of testing as does Windows.

Comment: Simply put, **it's a different message**. Instead of each window receiving a `WM_CLOSE` message when the system is shutting down, each window will get a `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message, followed by a `WM_ENDSESSION` message. So, applications are still notified of a pending shutdown and can react accordingly, whether that system shutdown is initiated by `shutdown /s` or any other route. See also: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms700677 and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080421-00/?p=22663

Comment: Compare and contrast [bitcoin's code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/99813a9745fe10a58bedd7a4cb721faf14f907a4/src/qt/winshutdownmonitor.cpp#L24) with [the correct way to handle these messages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms700677(v=vs.85)#best-practices-for-handling-shutdown-in-windows-vista) ([furthermore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/shutdown/shutdown-changes-for-windows-vista)).

Comment: It's curious that you say `shutdown /s` "simply initiates the normal Windows shutdown procedure which does whatever is necessary", when several people here are reporting different behaviour between `shutdown /s` and normal (Start menu) shutdown.

Comment: @CodyGray Note however that the claim on the Github thread is not that Windows is failing to send `WM_CLOSE` but that it is failing to send `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think perhaps you meant to reply to JdeBP instead of me? I didn't link or mention a GitHub thread.

Answer (score 5):

Generally `shutdown /s` does not send any "close" messages. It call one of few Win32 API functions for shutting down Windows system.

These functions in turn notify aplications about shutdown/restart event via `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and `WM_ENDSESSION` messages.

Programs can then agree or try to prevent pending shutdown by responsing properly to `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, eg. for stopping cleanly, etc.

So, in theory after issue `shutdown /s` command, there is some "close" messages send to all programs and you don't need doing anything special for that.

But `shutdown /s` is somehow specific (or buggy?), and makes Windows ignore responses for `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` so Bitcoin Core cannot shut down in a clean way. I see this behaviour on Windows 7, and as appears from linked GitHub issue Windows 10 has it too.

One answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/difference-between-shutdown-s-and-stop-computer/7239fa8e-db5b-4502-9dbd-c0c214a30a94) suggests that more "normal" (like from start menu) shutdown is performed via PowerShell `Stop-Computer` command.

> At an API level, shutdown /s will be using one of the InitiateShutdown APIs (I'm not sure which one) whereas Stop-Computer most likely uses ExitWindowsEx.  The latter is more appropriate when run from an interactive session.

***Personally** I never trust Windows in such scenarios and stops any important programs manually. I even read some article about Windows killing apps if they do clean-up for too long, but I cannot find it now.*

You can read about shutdown procedure [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/shutting-down).

And if you want there is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/acinis/23290c49c9c4bdc3a6b525aa447e79df) which I used for testing.

Answer (score 4):

The command `shutdown /s` issues a forced reboot, as described in the output of `shutdown /?`:

> /t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
> The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
> **If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
> implied.**
>
> /f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.

[Abridged, emphasis mine.]

If you want applications to be able to cancel the shutdown, you need to use `shutdown /s /t 0` instead.

This doesn't explain why the behaviour you observe has changed, however.  I'm not sure whether the behaviour of Windows has changed or there has been a change in the Bitcoin application.

I do note that the [code here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/99813a9745fe10a58bedd7a4cb721faf14f907a4/src/qt/winshutdownmonitor.cpp#L24) appears to me to be incorrect (as pointed out by JdeBp in the comments to another answer) and appears to be depending entirely on ShutdownBlockReasonCreate, which presumably the forced shutdown overrides.  I believe that if the code waited until the client shutdown was complete before responding to the `WM_ENDSESSION` message, then the client shutdown would be allowed to complete, provided it took no more than five seconds to do so.

Comment: ... it is also entirely possible that the forced reboot simply kills all the user's applications outright, I'm not sure.  I can confirm that `shutdown /s` has behaved in this way at least as far back as Windows 8.1.

Comment: Harry Johnston thanks for this insight. It seems to me to verge on the criminal that this is by design, but it explains a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, it's not true that Windows shuts down without notifying programs when you use `shutdown /s`.

---

***EDIT**: as pointed out in Harry Johnston's answer, that actually depends on whether you allow a timeout. I always use `shutdown /s /t 0` (timeout 0 seconds), since the default is 30 seconds and I don't want to wait a while before anything happens! Incredible as it sounds though, using (or defaulting to)  **any** timeout period is inextricably linked to **horrifying save behaviour**: Windows will actually then **force-terminate your processes without offering you the chance to intervene!** And this horrifying behaviour is even by design! (See the usage output from `shutdown /?`.)*
*My answer is for `shutdown /s /t 0`, meaning you are not expecting to sit there for up to 30 seconds before anything happens.*

---

You may demonstrate for yourself that Windows notifies programs. Just edit a text file in Notepad, and before saving your changes, issue `shutdown /s /t 0`. When the shutdown starts, Notepad prevents it, showing that it has received the notification from Windows:

[image]

If you then press Cancel (or if you take no action), you are returned to your Windows Desktop, where Notepad can be seen prompting for save:

[image]

However, it may be that recent changes in Windows shutdown have introduced a more subtle bug: in what I believe is an attempt to mitigate its annoying shutdowns for updates, Windows has relatively recently acquired the habit of attempting to restore my programs from last time, a feature that doesn't work too well and which I detest, and so I always use `shutdown /s /t 0` and `shutdown /r /t 0` instead of the Start menu (because thankfully that bypasses the program restore bit). But recently I've noticed that on launching Chrome, it often now reports that it was shut down incorrectly, which does support the idea that Windows has acquired a defect in this area:

[image]

But I've never seen a complete failure to notify running apps that would fail the above Notepad test, not in any version of Windows. For information, this is my current version of Windows, as reported by WinVer (I've heard of general problems in version 2004 so I am not moving to that yet):

[image]

Comment: As a quick test I did exactly what you say: notepad, text, then type the command. Windows did shut down without Notepad prompting to save changes. Interesting you have a different behaviour.

Comment: @user1532080 yeah that is weird. I've added pics to my answer. What version info does WinVer give you?

Comment: Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.1082). So mine's older... Oh well, I've clicked a button, it's now upgrading to 2004. We'll see then.

Comment: @user1532080 Good luck with 2004... :) I guess it's been well, 6 months now, so hopefully they've fixed the issues there were when it first came out. btw I was having trouble adding the pics but they are all there now.

Comment: Thanks! Taskbar and start menu now have a transparent background :D Anyway, did the same test, same behaviour (iow no notification of Notepad). Version 2004 (19041.508).

Comment: @user1532080 Not Windows version then; tbh I'm not surprised as I'm sure I'd have noticed if 1903 did that. Try any checks you can think of, like `sfc /scannow`, and scanning with Windows Defender and the free MalwareBytes. And try the Bitcoin stuff on a PC that doesn't have this behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried disabling  Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options > "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart."? Despite the description sounding slightly unrelated, setting that to Off no longer gave me weirdly restarting applications in Windows 10, up to the current 20H2.

Comment: Actually it is true. Only GUI programs get the notification. Console programs do not.

Comment: @Joshua, doesn't a console program that registers for [CTRL+CLOSE signals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-close-signal) receive one during shutdown?

Comment: I'm on 1909, and I see the same behaviour as @user1532080, i.e., notepad prompts when using Stop-Computer but not when using shutdown /s.

Comment: @HarryJohnston this is very interesting because again it shows it's not adequate for us to assume that `shutdown /s` "simply initiates the normal Windows shutdown procedure which does whatever is necessary". If that was true, `shutdown /s` would behave the same as the normal (Start menu) shutdown, but you have again demonstrated that it can behave differently.

Comment: See my newly posted answer; `shutdown /s` and `shutdown /s /t 0` behave differently.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh! :)

Comment: @Ray I have seen that "Use my sign-in info" option before, but currently it's not present on any of the machines I use. Possibly the availability of that option is controlled by a policy setting. I take it you are seeing the option in 20H2?

Comment: @RegEdit Yes, I've never seen it being hidden, it's at the very bottom of said screen, in the "Privacy" section, below "Show account details such as my email address on the sign-in screen.", the only other option in that section. If there's a group policy overriding it, it _should_ be grayed out with a yellow warning text at the top of the page.

Comment: @RegEdit Speaking of which, I noticed an option new in 2004 directly targeting this problem, right above the "Privacy" section. It's called "Restart apps: Automatically save my restartable apps when I sign out and restart them after I sign in." - it's off for me aswell. S. https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-stop-windows-10-restarting-your-apps-after-you-login